# Scala macros and separate compilation units

Tags: scala, macros, compilation, jvm, scala-macros

Is this limitation going to be overcome in the future? Or is there some way to get around this that I'm not aware of?

Right now I have a project where I would like to use macros, but they would need to depend on types specific to that project. Having a separate compilation unit for the macro would require me to introduce another one to hold the common types, which I'm not willing to do every time I write a macro.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, we recognize that as a problem. Getting rid of this limitation is very high on our priority list.

Comment: Will make it to 2.11?

Comment: Definitely not in 2.11.0, which is probably going to be released quite soon. 2.11.x is also very unlikely, maybe with some sort of a plugin, but it's too early to tell.

Comment: At flatMap 2015, I gave a workshop with one of the demonstrations showing our new macro engine built within the scala.meta project. We've made a lot of progress with scala.meta, but it's still not even alpha, so it's hard to predict when/how it'll become part of the standard distribution. We expect to release a beta version next year, and in the meanwhile you could take a look at the demo from flatMap here: https://github.com/scalameta/flatmap2015.

Answer (score 0):

Both [Scala IDE](http://scala-ide.org/docs/current-user-doc/features/scalacompiler/index.html) and [Scalor Maven Plugin](https://github.com/random-maven/scalor-maven-plugin) 
support same-project macro compilation scopes.