# macro implementation not found (scala 2.13.3)

Tags: scala, scala-macros

I'm using the RunningStrategies class in my Scala code to define a set of running strategies. To create an instance of RunningStrategies, I'm using the apply method along with a variable number of arguments representing the different strategies. To achieve this, I have also defined a macro called RunningStrategiesMacros.

However, when I try to use RunningStrategies with some strategies, I get the following error message: "macro implementation not found: apply". The error seems to be related to the fact that I'm trying to use the macro implementation in the same compilation run that defines it.

RunningStrategy:

```
package com.dv.phoenix.brandsafety.models

object RunningStrategy extends Enumeration {
  type RunningStrategy = Value

  val
  MonitoringOnly,
  BlockingOnly,
  MonitoringAndBlockingInherent,
  MonitoringAndBlockingRecalculate
  = Value
}
```

RunningStrategies:

```
package com.dv.phoenix.brandsafety.models

import com.dv.phoenix.brandsafety.models.RunningStrategy.RunningStrategy
import com.dv.phoenix.brandsafety.utils.RunningStrategiesMacros

import scala.language.experimental.macros
case class RunningStrategies private (runningStrategies: Set[RunningStrategy])
object RunningStrategies {
  def apply(strategies: RunningStrategy*): RunningStrategies = macro RunningStrategiesMacros.applyImp
}
```

RunningStrategiesMacro:

```
package com.dv.phoenix.brandsafety.utils

import com.dv.phoenix.brandsafety.models.RunningStrategies
import com.dv.phoenix.brandsafety.models.RunningStrategy.RunningStrategy

import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

object RunningStrategiesMacros {
   def applyImp(c: blackbox.Context)(runningStrategies: c.Expr[RunningStrategy]*): c.Expr[RunningStrategies] = {
    import c.universe._

    val hasMonitoringAndBlockingInherent = runningStrategies.map(_.tree.toString).contains(s"${RunningStrategy.getClass.getName.stripSuffix("$")}.${RunningStrategy.MonitoringAndBlockingInherent}")
    val hasMonitoringAndBlockingRecalculate = runningStrategies.map(_.tree.toString).contains(s"${RunningStrategy.getClass.getName.stripSuffix("$")}.${RunningStrategy.MonitoringAndBlockingRecalculate}")

    if (hasMonitoringAndBlockingInherent && hasMonitoringAndBlockingRecalculate) {
      c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "runningStrategies cannot include both RunningStrategy.MonitoringAndBlockingInherent and RunningStrategy.MonitoringAndBlockingRecalculate")
    } else {
      c.Expr(q"RunningStrategies(Set(..$runningStrategies))")
    }
  }

}
```

Usuage:

```
override protected val runningStrategies: RunningStrategies = RunningStrategies(MonitoringOnly, MonitoringAndBlockingInherent, MonitoringAndBlockingRecalculate)
```

I got the following error:

```
macro implementation not found: apply
(the most common reason for that is that you cannot use macro implementations in the same compilation run that defines them)
  override protected val runningStrategies: RunningStrategies = RunningStrategies(MonitoringOnly, MonitoringAndBlockingInherent, MonitoringAndBlockingRecalculate)
```

I have noticed that the [scala-logging](https://github.com/lightbend-labs/scala-logging/blob/main/src/main/scala-2/com/typesafe/scalalogging/LoggerImpl.scala) library has managed to solve this problem with their [LoggerImpl](https://github.com/lightbend-labs/scala-logging/blob/main/src/main/scala-2/com/typesafe/scalalogging/LoggerImpl.scala)  and [LoggerMacro](https://github.com/lightbend-labs/scala-logging/blob/main/src/main/scala-2/com/typesafe/scalalogging/LoggerMacro.scala) classes. Can someone explain how they were able to do this and how I can apply the same technique to my RunningStrategiesMacro?

Comment: It's difficult to say exactly (you haven't provided the code where you override `protected val runningStrategies`) but something like https://github.com/DmytroMitin/SO-Q75847326-macros-demo `RunningStrategies` and `RunningStrategiesMacros` depend on each other (because you use `c.Expr[...]` macro signatures rather than `c.Tree`), so they should go to the same subproject (`macros`). Where you override `runningStrategies` (my `App`, macro application) should be different from `macros`, so it goes to `core`.

Comment: Both `core` and `macros` depend on `RunningStrategy`, so `RunningStrategy` can go to `macros` or to `common`.

Comment: https://github.com/DmytroMitin/SO-Q75847326-macros-demo/commit/c6d9f1f69d1ff901ab852b93bab91c4597e72fe5

Comment: Awesome! thanks!!  (I'm still encountering a problem while trying to implement the `applyImp`. I need to abort the `RunningStrategies(MonitoringAndBlockingInherent, MonitoringAndBlockingRecalculate)` part. If you have a solution for this, that would be wonderful!)

Comment: Update: I managed to solve it, i updated the `applyImp` - probably there nicely way to do it

Comment: If you have more questions feel free to open a new question

Comment: All solved, cheers @DmytroMitin 

Comment: Work on raw strings doesn't look good (especially those `.stripSuffix("$")`). It's better to compare by `Symbol` https://github.com/DmytroMitin/SO-Q75847326-macros-demo/commit/81fc7dd4491805dcc799864242eea0ed02abe4ce See https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/symbols-trees-types.html

Comment: One more option is to use `c.eval` https://github.com/DmytroMitin/SO-Q75847326-macros-demo/commit/e5878860c6fd0945fd7782d23eb2de61e67e63ad

Comment: Thanks! I used it and its looks much better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your question you described your package structure but not your project structure. Packages and subprojects are different concepts

[Why can't sbt/assembly find the main classes in a project with multiple subprojects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75700171/why-cant-sbt-assembly-find-the-main-classes-in-a-project-with-multiple-subproje)

You should have different subprojects if you want to use [macros in Scala 2](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html)

https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Macro-Projects.html

Firstly, let's refresh the terminology. This is a macro **definition**

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros

def foo(): Unit = macro fooImpl
```

This is a macro **implementation**

```
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

def fooImpl(c: blackbox.Context)(): c.Tree = {
  import c.universe._
  println("test")
  q"""_root_.scala.Predef.println("foo")"""
}
```

This is a macro **application** (call site, macro expansion)

```
foo()
// at compile time: scalac: test
// at runtime: foo
```

In Scala 2 macro implementations must be compiled before macro applications (the compile time of macro applications i.e. macro expansion is the runtime of macros). So it's macro **implementations** and macro **applications** that must be in different compile units. For example in different subprojects of your project. Or in `src/main/scala` and `src/test/scala` of the same project (main code is compiled before tests). Where macro definitions are is not so important. They can be in the same compilation unit/subproject as macro implementations (maybe in the same file/class) or in the same as macro applications or in their own.

In `scala-logging`, macro definitions

```
def error(message: String): Unit = macro LoggerMacro.errorMessage
```

and macro implementations

```
def errorMessage(c: LoggerContext)(message: c.Expr[String]): c.universe.Tree = ...
```

are in the same project (in different files but this is not necessary, they can be in the same file) but macro applications

```
logger.error(msg)
```

are in `src/test/scala` https://github.com/lightbend-labs/scala-logging/blob/v3.9.5/src/test/scala/com/typesafe/scalalogging/LoggerSpec.scala . And other macro applications will be also in different compilation units i.e. client projects using `scala-logging` as a dependency.

In your project

```
def apply(strategies: RunningStrategy*): RunningStrategies = macro RunningStrategiesMacros.applyImp
```

is a macro definition and

```
def applyImp(c: blackbox.Context)(strategies: c.Expr[RunningStrategy]*): c.Expr[RunningStrategies] = ...
```

is a macro implementation. But you should re-organize your project having at least two subprojects and place macro applications

```
override protected val runningStrategies: RunningStrategies = RunningStrategies.apply(MonitoringOnly, MonitoringAndBlockingInherent, MonitoringAndBlockingRecalculate)
```

to a different subproject

```
lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  scalaVersion := "2.13.10"
)

// where you override runningStrategies goes here
lazy val core = project
  .dependsOn(macros)
  .settings(
    commonSettings,
    scalacOptions += "-Ymacro-debug-lite" // convenient to debug macro expansions
  )

// utils/RunningStrategiesMacros go here
lazy val macros = project
  .settings(
    commonSettings,
    // necessary for macro implementations
    libraryDependencies += scalaOrganization.value % "scala-reflect" % scalaVersion.value
  )
```

---

[Is there any trick to use macros in the same file they are defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27919726/is-there-any-trick-to-use-macros-in-the-same-file-they-are-defined)

[Possible to identify/use Scala macros using reflection or similar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60102862/possible-to-identify-use-scala-macros-using-reflection-or-similar)

[Using scala macro from java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25078538/using-scala-macro-from-java)

[Implicit materialization in the same module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65307700/implicit-materialization-in-the-same-module)

[Def macro - scala 2.13 - not found: value cond](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63130104/def-macro-scala-2-13-not-found-value-cond)

[Scala macros and separate compilation units](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21994764/scala-macros-and-separate-compilation-units)

[Auto-Generate Companion Object for Case Class in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74497076/auto-generate-companion-object-for-case-class-in-scala)